# android emulator time synchronization

Tags: android, time, emulation, synchronization

Is there some way to synchronise emulator time and system time with milliseconds accuracy? So the call `System.currentTimeMillis()` would return the same time as call `gettimeofday()` in C?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the question 100%.

If you look in `dalvik/vm/native/java_lang_System.c` you will see:

```
static void Dalvik_java_lang_System_currentTimeMillis(const u4* args, JValue* pResult)
{
    struct timeval tv;

    UNUSED_PARAMETER(args);

    gettimeofday(&tv, (struct timezone *) NULL);
    long long when = tv.tv_sec * 1000LL + tv.tv_usec / 1000;

    RETURN_LONG(when);
}
```

So System.currentTimeMillis() calls gettimeofday() - at least in the dalvik implementation that I am looking at.

What about using an app like [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync&hl=da) to set the time on the emulator. It uses the ntp protocol which you could also use on your host PC.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android does [not](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4581) [allow](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12497) time to be set by an app without root. So you can set time only if you [root the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator).