# Uninstall Android Settings

Tags: android, settings

I was wondering if it is possible to uninstall the default Settings application on an Android emulator. I have already tried "adb uninstall com.android.settings" but it comes up with Failure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`com.android.settings` is not a user installable application. It lives in the system folders and as such is not user removable. If you rooted your device you could remove it but I suspect many applications rely on it and removing it will cause problems.  That said root your emulator and try: [How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)

You can always create a new emulator image if you mess up the rooted one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but you can remove default applications with apps such as [Titanium Backup](http://matrixrewriter.com/android/) if you're a rooted user.

** EDIT ** 
Overlooked the emulator part of the question - apologies.

<s>I would advise against uninstalling it, as I'm not sure you can get it back - it's one of those things that you def need on your phone.</s>

At least do a backup (Nandroid or otherwise) before removing it, so you can get it back easily if you make a mistake/need it again.

Comment: why would you need to do a nandroid backup of an emulator?