# Root Access on Android SDK (Emulator)

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I have installed SQLite Editor app on the emulator but its showing that ;The application don’t have root permission. Tried apps like SuperUser to provide root access bur unable to do the same.

What is the best way to gain root access from Emulator itself? Please post the step by step process to gain the root access on Android SDK.

Comment: this answer did worked on emulator 2.3 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator

Answer (score 3):

Use the shell, that already gives you root access on the emulator:

```
(on your computer)
$ adb -e shell
$ cd /data/data/org.myapp/databases
$ sqlite3 mydb.db
```

AFAIK, you can't give give an app super user access on the emulator by installing the Superuser.apk.

Comment: This is correct, and works as long as you have a “Google APIs ... System Image”, and *not* a “Google Play ... System Image”.