# Android Emulator as `LowRamDevice`

Tags: android, ram, activity-manager

There's a method `ActivityManagerCompat.isLowRamDevice()`, and I'm trying to figure out how to test it. I've tried the following to get it to return true, but it's always false:

- Create a new emulator with 128 MB of RAM (Still returns false)
- `adb shell setprop ro.config.low_ram true` (Fails. Doesn't change the property)
- `add shell setprop debug.force_low_ram true` (Sets the property, but need a development build of Android)
- Searching online for a "Low Ram Emulator" to test with

**How can I test `ActivityManagerCompat.isLowRamDevice()` without compiling the OS from scratch?**

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer: You need root access on the Emulator

Then you can do: `adb shell setprop ro.config.low_ram true`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668555 for how to get root access on an emulator.