# No app installed still USB debugging error

Tags: android, android-studio

I rooted my Android Samsung Galaxy J7.
**Details:** SM-J700F, Marshmallow 6.0.1, API level 23.

I'm building several applications through my Android studio and testing on this Samsung real device. It was working fine, before I root this phone, but when I rooted this phone and also upgraded Samsung firmware, I'm getting this problem when I just open the Android studio. (Please note,I got error when I just open the Android Studio, not any particular project) And also that testing app is uninstalled Still getting this **error:**

> "Because an app is obscuring a permission request, Settings can't verify your response"**[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MHCT.jpg)

I **already turned on Developer options**, and allowed USB debugging. Now how can I test and practice Android apps?

Comment: How can I do that? I also searched a lot in other forums. Where is that option? Is it available in Galaxy J7?

Comment: just add emulator for now

Comment: Already my PC is very slow, not possible. Please give me for this error solution. Also there are lots of apps running on my J7 like Amazon, paytm, google apps they all are working fine!

Comment: connect your phone and hit this in terminal "adb devices" and check your device is connected or not.

Comment: have you seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator) ?

Comment: @Nil It is showing: 3300a32ab541a2ab unauthorized

Comment: @bhupathituraga Isn't that link is for Emulator? I want solution for real device

Comment: It's Root process issue. check [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-lg-g3/help/unable-to-access-adb-t2830087).

Comment: is your rooted device has targeted version of your app

Comment: @PriyankaSingh, You need to revoke developer access and authorize computer again,  please check this [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized

Comment: @Nil It is working my dear! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [because an app is obscuring a permissions request, Settings can't verify your response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681145/because-an-app-is-obscuring-a-permissions-request-settings-cant-verify-your-re)