# because an app is obscuring a permissions request, Settings can't verify your response

Tags: android

[image]While I allow USB debugging, tap on OK button, Messaging has comes

> because an app is obscuring a permissions request, Settings can't
>   verify your response

The error is coming in allowing USB debugging.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have wasted more than 2 hours on this.
Just turn off shortcut ball (or) assistive ball and then try it will work

Comment: Surya... please select a best answer to let us know which solution worked the best for you in this case!! If none.. post yours on how you fixed this. (End of Review).

Comment: Oppo smart sidebar is the issue.

Answer (score 39):

Go to Settings -> Apps -> Special Access -> Draw Over Other Apps

See which apps have permission to draw over other apps, and turn them off one by one until the problem goes away.

Comment: After this message disappear. To make device connected restart phone.

Comment: Generally, third-party apps cause the problem. In my case, it was an app for screen recording and capturing.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same with my tablet. I restarted tablet and it worked.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It worked for me to !

Comment: Worked.Nokia 2.2-Android 10

Answer (score 26):

Turn off shortcut ball (or) assistive ball and then try it will work

[image]

Model : Oppo

Comment: this work for me, I got this error when want to use wifi debugging on xiaomi redmi 9 and disable quick ball

Comment: @FereshtehNaji, yes it is worked for me by disabling "Quick ball" on xiomi redmi 8 pro.

Comment: It worked for me. I turned off quick ball on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8.

Answer (score 13):

I found a post on [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/help/app-obscuring-permission-request-t3558930) that solved that problem. Here it is:

> I solved this as follows:
>   - Go to Settings > Apps > Settings icon (at the bottom).
>   - Then Advanced > Special access > Draw over the other apps.
>   - At the top right, in the scrolling menu, choose "Show system processes".
>   - Select "Floating dock" and disable "Permit drawing over other apps".

Answer (score 8):

May be **DevMike** trick is working but I solved this by `uncheck` the option of **verify apps over USB**.

Setting > Developer options > verify apps over USB & uncheck the verify apps over USB.

**Note:**

> > This setting specifies whether your device should allow Google to inspect apps installed over USB for possible harmful behavior.
> >
> > In order to install apps over USB you must also have USB debugging enabled and compatible software (such as the ADB tool supplied by Google to developers, though other software can also take advantage of this ability) on the connected computer.
> >
> > App developers may want to have this service disabled in order to speed up the process of loading their app onto their device for testing. If you are installing apps that you did not develop yourself over USB, it is recommended that you enable this.
> >
> > This setting has no effect on apps that are installed on the device itself, either from the Play store or from other sources.

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to put Android OS in **Safe-mode**.

For Samsung phones:

1. Hold the power button until three buttons will appear on the screen.
2. Hold the power-off button on the screen for a couple of seconds while the safe-mode prompt appears.
3. This will restart your phone to a safe-mode.
4. After you're done, you can bring the phone to normal operation by choosing the safe-mode prompt from the notifications.

> [image]

Comment: Followed all the comments up to hear, disabling all the overlapping apps and verify apps over USB and this was the only options which worked me straight up.

Comment: Same situation as @Mehrad. Disabled all draw over other apps (including system ones) and unchecked "verify apps over USB." Rebooted multiple times. No avail. This was the one solution that worked for me.

Comment: I have a Galaxy Note 4 and I could not connect. Note 4 has old OS, so could not goto SafeMode. So, I went to Ultra Power Saving mode which disables all the 3rd party apps. Then, I could accept the prompt. Thanks for giving the idea.

Answer (score 6):

Another cause is the Smart Pixels battery saving feature that is present on some custom Android ROMs; ie Resurrection Remix. Disabling Smart Pixels will solve the problem.

In Resurrection Remix the setting is in Settings > Resurrection Tools > Interface > Smart Pixels > Enable Smart Pixels. 
*Note:This setting is Disabled by default.*

Comment: OMG, I am looking for this since ages ... thanks a lot.
I could not recover my gmail account because of this. I could not update all app at once I could not share to gmail and a lot of over things because of this.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings → Apps → Special Access → Draw Over Other Apps
turn off YouTube.

Comment: They renamed the last item to 'Apps that can appear on top'. In my case, it was not youtube alone, so I disabled it for all apps.

Answer (score 6):

I had to turn off navigation gestures under the action and gestures settings.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, disable Smart Pixels in Resurrection Remix ROM settings. This answer is ONLY for those running R.R. with Smart Pixels enabled. This setting is not an app, so it doesn't show up under the "Display Over Other Apps" listing in settings. *Credit to Jebtrix*

Comment: Solved my issue ;)

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is to please restart your device or mobile
it will work...

Answer (score 3):

Enter into the safe mode and try connecting it. It works!

How to enter safe mode?

1. Power off your device.
2. Power on the device and press and hold the volume down key the moment you see the boot animation, until it boots up.
3. You could able to see safe mode in left right corner.
4. Try connecting now.
5. It will work.
6. Restart device to exit safe mode.

P.S: entering into safe mode might be different for some devices. Try Googling for your device model, if it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling an App named "Mobile Go"

it was having permission of running on top of screen, i think it's related to capture screen.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your permission issue on your phone, the problem may be caused by an app called "File manager" Either you can uninstall it, or if you want to keep it, go in "Settings -> Applications -> Settings -> Draw over other apps" and set the value to "No" for "File manager". If you don't find still...Go to settings and search 'draw over other apps'. Restart the device. worked for me!

Comment: This was the thing. I've found out the the problem was caused by having Twilight app having this setting on. After turning it off I was able to press the button for approving my PC.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off Assistive/Quick/Shortcut ball did the trick for me.
Also, try revoking the Debugging Permissions from Developer Options under USB debugging, and setting connection mode to Media Transfer.

Installing PdaNet+ App and Driver might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Opting for onscreen buttons instead of navigational gestures worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

@Terry Carmen's answer is acceptable for me, the problem is occuring with **Mobile Go** app, revoking the access permission to Draw over the apps solved!

Answer (score 1):

In my case probably messenger bubble was source of problem. After cloase messenger app it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

for me I had to turn off Edge Gestures on the Accessibility Services!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the **DU Recorder** app running. You can see the **orange camera icon** in the left side of picture you attached. What you need to do is to close the app. You can do it by dragging the camera icon to the X.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that the problem is due to some running app is preventing you from getting permission.

Combinating the answers above from Terry Carmen and Andrew,

**JUST TURN OFF ALL APPS AND TRY AGAIN**

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Lock and Unlock your device. That's all you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that Google is telling that not all cables are able to use MTP transfer.

If you are displayed wrong icons at the beginning it might be that the USB cable needs to be different and most likely unique to the device or at least have transfer capability.

Be aware if MTP does not work, your cable might be wrong.