# Debugging C++ code of an Android App using lldb from the console

Tags: android, c++, remote-debugging, lldb

I would like to know how I can debug an Android app by using lldb.
I mean using lldb from console not over Android Studio.

From what I found out, Android Studio is doing this:

1. Pushing the app to the device
2. Starting this app
3. Pushing lldb-server to the device
4. Starting lldb-server on the remote device
5. Forwarding the ports
6. Connecting to the local port which is forwarded to the device

I would like to achieve the same using lldb from the console.

Let's say I have already lldb-server on the remote device (because Android Studio did this already for me), what do I need to do is to connect to an App using lldb from the console?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried, but maybe this could help:

- [LLDB remote debugging](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html)
- [Debugging C++ native libraries in Android using command line](https://www.sh-zam.com/2019/05/debugging-krita-on-android.html)

Additionally:

- ensure that APK's native libraries (lib*.so) are having debug info/symbols. I pull the apk locally, locate .so file, and check the output of [binutils nm](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) utility. When you get familiar with your .so files only checking the size of the .so file could be enough.
- one can debug by attaching to a running process/application ([attach](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html#id8)) and in some cases you need to debug application on application start ([run](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html#launching-a-locally-built-process-on-the-remote-machine)).
- in some debugging cases phone/emulator requires [root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds/45668555#45668555) (file manipulations)
- if you manage to debug C++ libs within Android Studio - check Debug+Console and Debug+LLDB output tabs to find interesting commands/options/steps
- the procedure looks quite complicated and fragile - arm yourself with patience, don't ignore warnings and don't skip steps.