# Adb root doesn't return anything on android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, adb, root

I'm using an Android Emulator to develop app on Visual Studio 2019. I want to access files created by my app. I use the File Explorer on Android Device Monitor, but it shows I have no permission to access the 'user' folder. So I try to change the permission by using adb command, adb root, but it returned nothing.

Device's information
[image]

File and folder permission
[image]

The results
[image]

As you see, I need to check the files in `user` folder, but `adb root` seems do nothing without error.

Answer (score -1):

After I updated the Command-line tools from 1.0 to 2.1, it showed the error, `adbd cannot run as root in production builds` after ran `adb root`.
Refer to [ADB root is not working on emulator (cannot run as root in production builds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds/45668555#45668555), I created another device using the setting below.  And finally `adb root` worked. I still don't understand the reason. I suppose the Google Play Store has some kind of protection mechanism?
[image]