# Rooting ICS emulator; pushing su fails with "Out of memory"

Tags: android, android-emulator, su

I'm trying to root my ICS AVD, and have tried this:

```
adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system  
adb push su /system/xbin/su  
adb shell chmod 06755 /system  
adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
```

It fails with the following error:

> failed to copy 'su' to '/system/xbin/su': Out of memory

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your title is way confusing. Afaik the emulator instance is always rooted. Please change your title to fit the question.

Comment: I believe the emulator allows `adb shell` to be executed, but doesn't have the `su` executable installed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This blog](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2011/12/10/installing-susuperuser-apk-in-icsandroid-4-0-emulator/) explains the problem:

> To avoid the "Out of memory" error when trying to copy the su-executable to `/system/bin`, you need to start the emulator manually with a large `–partion-size` argument:
>
> ```
> $ emulator -avd MYNAME -partition-size 300
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> $ adb remount
> $ adb push su /system/bin/su
> $ adb shell chmod 06755 /system/bin/su
> ```

Note that `MYNAME` above is the name of the emulator. Also note that if you are using snapshots, you will need to start the emulator without it due to the change in hardware configuration. Append `-no-snapshot-load` to do so.

Comment: This works in Windows. Be in the command prompt, in C:\adt\sdk\tools, or wherever your tools directory is. If you're in Explorer, you can shift+right click for an "open command prompt here" option.

Answer (score 8):

With this you'll have 512MB of size on /system

ICS is the name I gave to my android emulator:

android-sdk-linux/tools$ emulator -avd ICS -partition-size 512

Comment: This is the correct answer and it came a week before the top-voted answer!  Not formatted quite so pretty though.

Comment: Formatting has value, but even more: references (in this case to the blog) has high value, apparently more value than speed.