# Unable to root the Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, root

I want to root the Android Virtual Device (Emulator) for some development purpose. Please guide me how to do it. I need help.

Comment: hope this link helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator

Comment: The emulator is already rooted, in the sense the adb runs as root, which is all you should need for development purposes.  If you want to play with so-called "root apps" ie those which use a hacked "su" as a shim to launch root helpers, then you will need to install such, as described at the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Sushil is wrong the emulator AVd already is rooted by design

Comment: The emulator is indeed normally already rooted, but it's not clear what claim you believe to be "wrong"