# Is there any way of viewing database in Android Studio Emulator 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sqlite, ddms

I have noticed in my Android Studio 2.3.3 , in the android emulator, after opening the ddms, in file explorer, I cannot open the data folder.

When I searched abt in google they said that the emulator is not rooted. Only for rooted devices it can be done.

So my question is that, can we root an emulator and open in Android Studio?

Or

Can we see the contents in the data folder without rooting the device after applying some sort of patch?

But if i run the same in genymotion emulator its working fine, I can dig into data folder in the file explorer of ddms

Please help

Comment: you know that internet search takes less time than asking a question here? it also returns question which was already asked here ...

Comment: see if this helps https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Root an Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075702/how-to-root-an-android-emulator)

Comment: If you use the genymotion emulator you can access the data/data/projectname/databases directory. Using adv (tools/Android/Android Device Monitor) you can copy(pull) the file and then open it in an SQLite management tool (I use SQLite Manager which is a browser extension). You also reverse the process, copying the file back (push it onto the device), e.g. after making and desired changes.