# Why doesn't Android Device Monitor show data while my API is 24

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat

I'm new to Android and all I wanted to do was to check my database. I successfully managed that with API 23 and below. However if my Emulator API is bigger than 23, it can't open data folder in my Android Device Monitor. Why is that?

Comment: It's a bug/limitation in the IDE, as far as I have been able to tell. Android Studio 2.4 has a new tool for browsing device/emulator contents.

Comment: I read some posts about that, because I also have this problem. They all say, that root access is required to your emulator. I haven´t tried it out, but maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator

Comment: In API 24 and below there are new File system Permission Changes that you may want to get familiar with. Check this link out: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm