# How to enable arm native bridge in android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, arm

I wish to test ARM applications in an android emulator (SDK) running android 6.0 with an Intel x86 architecture.

Since the ARM (armeabi-v7a) architecture is very slow, compared to Intel which takes advantage of Intel(R) Hardware Accelerated Execution,  Intel(R) Virtualization Technology (VT)
switching to such an option is not an intended solution.

I have noted in Android x86 (RemixOS), it supports native arm applications through the arm bridge. This is possible though the use of `libhoudini.so` libraries.
I [rooted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473415/7551330) my virtual device device in emulator, and tried pushing these libraries through adb in `/system/lib`, unfortunately this didn't work.

Is there something that I am doing wrong or maybe there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: It is very slow because it is emulated is that what you are trying to say?  Where is this code being bridged to?  You have an arm connected to your x86 computer?  What I see so far is a software emulator and/or you natively build the applications for the target you are running on.

Comment: @old_timer Precisely I am using a software emulator (aka android SDK rev 25 ) with avd running android 5,6 and 7 but all use x86 architecture. What I want to achieve is placing arm libraries in these x86 avd's so I can run arm applications. Similar to what Remix OS does (i.e it has this arm native bridge and runs arm applications although it is x86 in terms of architecture) 
The overall reason is performance, x86 avds are much faster than armeabi based. I hope you understand

Comment: @xavier_fakerat With Genymotion emulator (you can test it with [Genymotion On Demand on AWS](https://www.genymotion.com/on-demand/)) I just drag & drop ARM Translation zip file, and it works after the reboot.

Comment: @kenorb Thanks will try that out