# Root access on android studio 3.4

Tags: android, android-studio, root, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio 3.4.2 latest i tried to create multiple different version android virtual devices but non of them is rooted.. i try to install supersu and tried to start android virtual device with emulator -writable-system command and tried to root with upload su in system but when i reboot emulator after that it stop working or lose root.. so kindly tell me how can i make android emulator root permenantly? also i dont want root access on shell i want root access on virtual device

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator

Comment: i tried this method and one of its method is giving me root permission succesfully but as soon as i reboot android it stops working

Answer (score 1):

Hi it seems that you are using one of the newer android images, thus from API 29 (Android 10) their is no (straight forward) way to mount system as RW.

Following instructions out there on the web to disable-verity and reboot, will cause the emulator to hang and never reboot. However this I can say at-least for images provided by default by the AVD Manager, maybe it would work for custom AOSP built images.