# How to root Android 9 Android studio emulator in order to use with apps?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, root, android-9.0-pie

I tried this method to root (answers starts "How to root android emulator tested on Android 7.1.1/ Nougat") [How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)  I did all commands but emulator is not rooted. Why these answers are so old? Do we need to wait for methods to root later versions of Android or there are some information about it but I can't find?

Comment: `Why these answers are so old?` because they were given long ago, I guess. It is better if you tell us why you need to root the emulator. There likely is some better way to do what you want.

Comment: I want to root it because I want to test old apps I have if they're working on Android 9 Pie because I want to buy phone with Android 9.

Comment: I still see no connection between `test old apps` and `root it`. Why do you need to root it to test?

Comment: Because some of apps require root.