# Reset all apps cache and data on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, caching

I need to make an app which erases all of Android's data and cache. I need it because I have an Android device which will be used by different people at different points in time, so I want a way to protected the different users data. I have found a few methods to do erase the data, but they all need root, such as running `adb clear` on all packages. Is there a method to clear all apps data and cache without rooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need root access for that.

It is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).
The files you are talking about are app-specific files, and other apps cannot access them, unless they have root access.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to simulate root access on Android Studio or will I need to root a real Android device to run tests?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator for rooting an emulator.