# Which Android Emulator image do contain 'su'?

Tags: android, android-emulator, root, su

How to know which Emulator image will contain `su`?
I can see that often it only contains `su` or `google play`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `adb root` and you get a `root` shell ... otherwise `su` needs to be manually installed.
However, when already having a `root` shell available, installing it isn't much of a problem.
All images are rooted, but SDK apps requesting escalation of privileges do rely upon `su`.
This question here generally duplicates: [How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)

`adb` shell scripting must:

- start the emulator
- run  `adb root`
- run  `adb shell`
- remount system partition
- `adb push` the `su` binary
- `chmod` to set permissions
- `exit`

---

Or to answer the question:

- start the emulator
- and check if the file exists, eg. with `adb shell stat /usr/bin/su`

Where `stat` gives this response, when it's not installed:

```
stat: '/usr/bin/su': No such file or directory
```

One could even loop all Android images installed in `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME`...
there's no "one click" solution, but `adb` can be fully automated with Bash or Batch. And one wouldn't even have to run the emulator, but can mount QCOW2 as a `nbd` network block device.